# I need to download Leonard Suskind video Lectures

Tags: download

Is there a way to download the physics video lectures using curl, mget, or wget.
accessing youtube and selecting download method (MP4) takes too long.

Any command line example would help greatly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `youtube-dl` utility:

- Check what formats are available for particular video:

  ```
  youtube-dl -F 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUZeZD9sytc'
  ```
- Then download the one with say best quality:

  ```
  youtube-dl -f18 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUZeZD9sytc'
  ```